# In Calvinism can a person reject the will of God

Tags: reformed-theology, will-of-god

As a Calvinist can a person reject the will of God?

Comment: This requires considerably more clarity and detail. If a 'person' rejects God's will (for a lifetime) then their eternal state will reflect that. Do you mean 'resist' the will of God ? As it stands, the question appears (to me) to be meaningless through overmuch brevity.

Comment: @NigelJ Could this be partly remedied by specifying "permanently" or "temporarily" as a qualifier?

Comment: First define what you mean by "the will of God" and explain who "a person" is within the context of your question. Then please show us the research you have already conducted into Calvinism/reformed theology which has led you to ask this "closed" question, i.e., a question that merely asks for a yes or no answer.  What's needed is an "open" question, one that lends itself to explaining the thinking/reasoning behind an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, there are two wills of God, his revealed will and his secret will.

His revealed will is all that he commands us to do, such as believe the gospel, repent of sins, live godly lives.  His revealed will is being resisted day after day.

His secret will is all that shall come to pass.  This cannot be thwarted by anyone.  All that has happened in the past and all that shall happen in the future is part of God's secret will, or part of his "eternal decree" which includes the whole history of the universe from its beginning to the end of days in every detail.. the sparrow that falls from the sky and the number of the hairs of your head.

Nebuchadnezzar expresses this almighty power of God as well as anyone:

*At the end of the days, I Nebuchadnezzar lifted up mine eyes unto heaven, and mine understanding returned unto me, and I blessed the MOST HIGH, and I praised and honoured him who lives forever, whose dominion is an everlasting dominion, and his kingdom is from generation to generation: and all the inhabitants of the earth are reputed as nothing; he does according to his will in the army of heaven, and among the inhabitants of the earth, and none can stay his hand, or say to him: What are you doing?* Daniel 4:34-35.

See also Job 12:10-23 and Isaiah 46:8-13..

*Remember this and show yourselves men; bring it again to mind, o you transgressors: remember the former things of old, for I am GOD and there is none else; I am God and there is none like me, declaring the end from the beginning, and from ancient times the things which are not yet done, saying, my counsel shall stand and I shall do all that I please... yea, I have spoken it, I also will bring it to pass; I have purposed it, I also will do it.*

It is he who opens hearts and he who hardens hearts; he chooses the objects of his grace and he chooses the objects of his wrath; both he chooses before they have been born; so that in our pride we are tempted to ask, Then why does he still blame us for who can resist his will?  But who are you to talk back to God?  He does all these things so we might praise the wonders of his grace.. for it is grace exclusively which makes one to differ from another, so that all boasting is excluded.  He does all things according to the counsel of his own will, Ephesians 1:11.

Others can use their own terminology. I get mine from the following verse:

*The secret things belong to the LORD our God: but those things that are revealed belong to us and to our children for ever, that we may do all the words of this law.*  Deuteronomy 29:29.

Comment: So poor Tim (let's say) goes into everlasting fire because God would not let him repent and believe?

Comment: Poor Tim has absolutely no desire to repent and believe.. even though he has all the evidence there is a God and has no excuse.  Mike repents and believes because of God's grace and ONLY because of God's electing grace.  Tim on the other hand is wicked and deserves to be punished.. in fact we all do.  I appreciate you just don't "get it"... but, in the Calvinist's opinion, if it is not all of election then it cannot be all of unmerited grace.

Comment: In Scripture God holds men responsible for their sin (including unbelief). That is all I need to know. God is sovereign in all things.  This i also know. The mechanism as to how this works I don't need to know. But I do know the only reason I am saved and not others is entirely due to God's grace. And I follow the psalmist in 131.

Comment: Andrew did have a desire to repent and believe because God's grace gave him that desire.  God has commanded Tim to repent but won't give him the desire or the ability.  It is the reprobation angle of Calvinism that sticks in my craw. +1 though.

Comment: @MikeBorden It is the whole of Adam's seed that has proved itself unfit for purpose and worthy only of destruction. And there is also that which occurred _before_ any of that happened : some were chosen _in Christ_ (not Adam) before the world was even founded. I suggest you stop listening to so-called 'Calvinists' and focus on the actual word of scripture. These people are not helping you. They try to reconcile by logic. But they use human logic, not Divine wisdom from above.